# Can't Fetch data - JavaScript async function from jsonplaceholder

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, jsonplaceholder

DOM does not render the info I pick from the API jsonplaceholder. Just want to render some authors and abstracts.

This is my HTML code, and JS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Blog - Lista de Comentarios</title>
<style>
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex article {
width: calc(50% - 20px);
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
border: 2px solid black;
}
.flex article:nth-child(even)
{
background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
select {
border: 2px solid tomato;
width: 80%;
padding: 20px;
margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
display: block;
font-size: 150%;
}
hr {
margin: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<select id="selectAutor">
<option value="" selected>Selecciona un autor</option>
<option value="1">Autor 1</option>
<option value="2">Autor 2</option>
<option value="3">Autor 3</option>
<!-- Añadir más opciones según sea necesario -->
</select>
<hr>
</header>
<section id="comentarios" class="flex">
<!-- esta es la superficie iterable que hay que repetir por cada comentario -->
<article>
<h3>Nombre del autor</h3>
<p>Email: correo@dominio.com</p>
<p>Comentario:</p>
<p>Texto del comentario</p>
</article>
</section>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {


// Función para obtener los comentarios de la API REST
async function obtenerComentarios() {
  const url = '...URL...jsonplaceholder...';
  
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const comentarios = await response.json();
    return comentarios;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error al obtener los comentarios:', error);
    throw new Error('Error al obtener los comentarios');
  }
}

// Función para mostrar los comentarios de un autor seleccionado
async function mostrarComentariosPorAutor(idAutor) {
  console.log('ID del autor seleccionado:', idAutor);
  try {
    // Obtener todos los comentarios
    const comentarios = await obtenerComentarios();
    console.log('Comentarios obtenidos:', comentarios);
    // Filtrar los comentarios del autor seleccionado
    const comentariosAutor = comentarios.filter(comentario => comentario.userId == idAutor);
    console.log('Comentarios del autor seleccionado:', comentariosAutor);

    // Seleccionar el contenedor de comentarios en el DOM
    const contenedorComentarios = document.getElementById('comentarios');
    contenedorComentarios.innerHTML = '';

    // Mostrar cada comentario del autor seleccionado en el DOM
    comentariosAutor.forEach(comentario => {
      const article = document.createElement('article');
      article.innerHTML = `
        <h3>Nombre del autor: ${comentario.name}</h3>
        <p>Email: ${comentario.email}</p>
        <p>Comentario:</p>
        <p>${comentario.body}</p>
      `;
      contenedorComentarios.appendChild(article);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error al mostrar los comentarios:', error);
  }
}

// Manejar el evento de cambio en el selector de autor
document.getElementById('selectAutor').addEventListener('change', event => {
    console.log('Evento de cambio detectado');
  const idAutor = parseInt(event.target.value);
  console.log('ID del autor seleccionado:', idAutor);
  if (idAutor) {
    mostrarComentariosPorAutor(idAutor);
  }
});

});
```

Comment: Please cut this down to a [mre], you may solve your own problem in the process. Take the [tour] and review [ask].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

I translated your code to english and added some demo JSON. it works:

https://jsfiddle.net/gtpo4j3m/

so I guess you should check your JSON response by doing something like:

```
const response = await fetch(url);
const comentarios = await response.json();
console.log('comentarios', comentarios);
```

The response should be similar to the getComments() function in the jsfiddle. What does it say?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that OP was referring to the resource https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com and therefore I prepared the following snippet to collect comments to posts a certain user (=author) has committed.

Maybe this is was OP wanted? In any case, there are a few patterns in here that might be helpful otherwise.

```js
// if you place this script tag UNDER your body 
// you will not need to use the DOMContentLoaded event
// and you can set up some global constants
const [autsel, cmtdisp] = ["selectAutor", "comentarios"].map(id => document.getElementById(id));

// asynchrounous IIFE: we are doing all the asynchronous stuff in here
(async function() {
  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/';

  try {
    // get users and comments:
    const [users, comments] = await Promise.all(["users", "comments"].map(v => fetch(url + v).then(r => r.json())));
    // comments are related to postIds and these are related to users (authors)
    // if you want to have comments per author your would need a two step lookup process.
    // Luckily the data in JSON placeholder follows a simple pattern: 
    // userId = 1+Math.floor((postId-1)/10)
    // We can use this to reorganize our comments:
    const cmts = comments.reduce((a, c) => {
      (a[1 + Math.floor((c.postId - 1) / 10)] ??= []).push(c);
      return a;
    }, {});
    autsel.innerHTML = users.map(u => `<option value="${u.id}">${u.name}</option>`).join("");
    autsel.addEventListener("change", showComments(cmts));
    showComments(cmts)({target:{value:1}}) // show comments for first author ...
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error getting users and comments:', error);
    throw new Error('Error getting users and comments');
  }
})();

function showComments(cmtsObj) {
  return function(ev) {
    const id = ev.target.value;
    cmtdisp.innerHTML = cmtsObj[id].map(c => `<article>
<h3>${c.name}</h3>
<p>Email: ${c.email}</p>
<p>Comentario:</p>
<p>${c.body}</p>
</article>`).join("\n")
  }
}
```

```css
article {
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: solid grey 1px
}
```

```html
<header>
  <select id="selectAutor">
  </select>
  <hr>
</header>
<section id="comentarios" class="flex">
</section>
```